# Can Iranians travel to Svalbard visa-free?

Tags: visas, air-travel, norway, iranian-citizens

From the Wikipedia article, [Visa requirements for Iranian citizens](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Iranian_citizens):

> Unlimited period under Svalbard Treaty.
>
> Everyone may, in principle, travel to Svalbard, and foreign citizens do not need a visa or a work or residence permit from Norwegian authorities in order to settle in Svalbard.

Also, In the provided sources in Wikipedia ([Spitsbergen-Svalbard.com](https://www.spitsbergen-svalbard.com/2011/10/05/visa-and-passport-requirements.html) and [sysselmesteren.no](https://www.sysselmesteren.no/en/visas-and-immigration/)) I didn't find anything regarding visa-free access.

But in the Wikipedia article [Svalbard Treaty](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Svalbard_Treaty) Iran isn't among the countries that have signed and ratified the treaty which was made effective about a century ago:

[image: map2]

From the same article:

> Uniquely, the archipelago is an entirely visa-free zone under the terms of the Svalbard Treaty.

Can Iranians go to Svalbard visa-free?

Note: I don't want to take a Schengen visa.

Comment: As I understand it it's not possible to reach Svalbard without passing through the Schengen area, so not wanting to get a Schengen visa could be an insurmountable problem.

Comment: You may want to check if you can reach Svalbard through Russia, but yes - you don't need a visa to the archipelago, but you'll need a visa for the transit areas you're going through while en route.

Comment: @phoog certainly possible to go there by boat from Russia. Not easy to book, but possible.

Comment: The dead link from the Wikipedia page should be replaced by https://www.sysselmesteren.no/en/visas-and-immigration/.

Comment: @PerManne edited

Answer (score 15, accepted):

All quotes from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Svalbard:

> Everybody may live and work in Svalbard indefinitely regardless of country of citizenship. The Svalbard Treaty grants treaty nationals equal right of abode as Norwegian nationals. Non-treaty nationals may live and work indefinitely visa-free as well.

> "It has been a chosen policy so far that we haven't made any difference between the treaty citizens and those from outside the treaty"

> Grounds for exclusion include lack of means of support, and violation of laws or regulations.

So, the Svalbard Treaty appears pretty irrelevant. *Everybody* may live in Svalbard, as long as they have means of support and don't violate any local laws.

> However, travelers who have a visa requirement to enter mainland Norway/the Schengen area must have a Schengen visa if they travel via mainland Norway/the Schengen area. This must be a double-entry visa so they can return to mainland Norway/the Schengen area.

If you find a way to travel to Svalbard avoiding the Schengen area, then you don't need any specific visa whatsoever. In practice however, most flights to Longyearbyen originate from Oslo and Tromsø. Even with a direct connection from a non-Schengen country, as an Iranian citizen, [you need *at least* a transit visa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_the_Schengen_Area#Airport_transit) unless exempted for some reason. Tromsø [doesn't offer any direct non-Schengen connections](https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/tos/routes), so the only realistic approach there would be [via Oslo](https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/osl/routes), for example Tehran - İstanbul - Oslo - Longyearbyen. Most other routes would probably require you do get a full Schengen visa; and it's possible you may need a full Schengen visa anyway (see comments).

Other options are very limited; possibly the occasional [cargo ship from Murmansk](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Barentsburg#By_boat) being one of the few options that do not require traversing the Schengen area. Iranian citizens do not require or [can easily obtain](https://evisa.kdmid.ru) a visa for Russia.

Comment: Do those cargo ships take passengers? If they do, do they take foreign citizens? It would not surprise me if the answer to both questions is "no".

Comment: @gerrit I do not know. I tried to poke around the Murmansk Shipping Company’s website, but it appears to be defunct. If you’re serious about this option (and I don’t know why you would be, doesn’t sound like the most pleasant trip), then digging up their phone number and trying to call someone would be the next logical step. And, you know… it’s Russia. Things which shouldn’t be possible may well be possible if you’re… convincing enough. 

Comment: @deceze I actually looked into [boats to Ostrovnoy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostrovnoy,_Murmansk_Oblast) in the past for trekking on the Kola Peninsula and I have an Ostrovnoy fridge magnet, but it seems unlikely I will ever go.

Comment: I am pretty sure that air-side transit between a non-schengen origin and a plane to Longyearbyen is not possible in Oslo. The planes from Oslo to Longyearbyen depart from the domestic area of the airport and AFAIK, there is just a simplified id check at the gate and no proper exit control. At least in the past, Norwegian citizens were allowed to travel using a driver's license as id and did not need 'proper' travel documents.

Comment: @gerrit there are cruises to Svalbard, most famously [hurtigrutten](https://www.hurtigruten.com/en-us/expeditions/cruises/faroe-islands-iceland-spitsbergen-island-hopping-in-and-around-the-arctic-northbound/) but it departs from Bergen (not sure if you can onboard in Iceland) so that wouldn't let you circumvent Schengen.

Comment: @papirtiger Iceland is also still Schengen.

Comment: Any boat calling in Svalbard would realistically originate either in Europe, Greenland, Canada or Russia. Among these, only Russia is of any interest to you if you want to go anywhere near visa-free.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Even with air-side transit I doubt the authorities would let someone without proper documents for Schengen into the domestic departure area.

Comment: @Anders Of course they won't and that is why I doubt that the transfer is possible with an air-side transit visa.

Comment: Maybe OP is planning to [solo sail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-handed_sailing) to Svalbard?

Comment: How do Russians get to and from [Barentsburg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barentsburg)?

Comment: @gerrit Arktikugol charters flights I think, eg tragically [Vnukovo Airlines Flight 2801](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vnukovo_Airlines_Flight_2801). There's helicopter shuttles from Longyearbyen to the various mining sites.

Comment: @jkej: [A ship with ice breaker capabilities may be required](https://nyheder.tv2.dk/2022-04-30-mikkel-beha-arbejder-paa-at-forvandle-sit-beroemte-skib), even during the summer.

Comment: @Peter Pffsshh… Go in a canoe, and just pick it up and walk over the ice.

Comment: @user1908704 Can non-Russians also book a ticket for the Arktikugol charters flights?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Maybe not in a a decade or two. OP may not be in a hurry. Maybe they could charter a private jet if they need to get there faster.

Comment: @deceze Was your second comment from bottom directed to me? If yes, then it was better to write it below the question.

Comment: @Snack You mean the boats calling in Svalbard comment? No, that just flowed from the comments about alternative cruises, directed at no one in particular.

Comment: @SnackExchange At the moment, flights between Svalbard and Russia are covered by the flight ban imposed due to the invasion of Ukraine. Arktikugol occasionally get exceptional approval from Norwegian authorities for flights with essential supplies to the Russian settlements, but tourist traffic is not allowed. Before covid, the flights were also open for tourists and not only employees.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo So boats are also banned because of the invasion?

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Flights from Oslo to Longyearbyen via Tromsø leave Oslo airport from the domestic area of the airport, but direct flights from Oslo to Longyearbyen leave Oslo airport from the international non-Schengen area of the airport.

Comment: @PerManne Yeah, sorry, you are right. I checked the current departure board before writing my comment, but didn't consider that there are flights from Oslo to Svalbard with a layover in Tromsø.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo "I am pretty sure that air-side transit between a non-schengen origin and a plane to Longyearbyen is not possible in Oslo" You'd be wrong there, as long as it's a flight without a Tromsö stopover - those depart from the non-Schengen sector